# React Router v4 - Nested Routes are not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

These are my main routes in Router.js

```
const Routes = () => {
    return ( 
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

And these are my nested routes under the homepage. Right now Dashboard and HomePage is working but Forget-Password and Sign-up are not working. I can only see WHITE BLANK PAGE WITHOUT ERROR.

```
render() {
     const {match} = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="container home-grid">
            <div className="featured">
                <Featured />
            </div>
            <div className="home-forms">
                <div className="logo">
                    <Logo />
                </div>
                <TransitionGroup className="route-page">
                    <CSSTransition
                        key={location.pathname}
                        timeout={{ enter: 800, exit: 800 }}
                        classNames="page"
                    >
                        <section className="route-section">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path={match.path} component={SignIn}/>
                                <Route path={`${match.path}forgot-password`} component={ForgotPassword} />


                            </Switch>
                        </section>
                    </CSSTransition>
                </TransitionGroup>
                <div className="footer-text">
                    <Text specialClass="footer"></Text>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Sign in is rendering but other routes are not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need some clarification: you first say `Sign-up is not working` then `Sign in is rendering`. First you say `white blank page` then you say `the other routes are not rendering`.

To recap this is what I understand: `/` works, `/dashboard` works, that code you show is the Home component , `/` is also the route for Signin, Signup does not exist and `/forgot-password` is giving you a white page.

So seems like the routing works fine. The white page is caused by nothing being rendered on that component?

Comment: Thx for your answer. Let me be more clear. Dashboard and HomePage is working, clearly. In home page as you can see i have forgot-password route and rendering sign in component as a start. I removed Sign Up route so, forgot-password is not working right now. It only shows blank page. Nothing more, not rendering, not doing anything. Its like forgot-password route doesnt even exist..

Comment: But are you rendering something in the ForgotPassword component?

Comment: Of course i am. My components are ready and was working. If i remove "exact" from Home route in Router.js, then Nested routes are working but Dashboard is not.

Answer (score 6):

What is happening when you reach the route `/forgot-password` is that the HomePage route does not match anymore because of `exact` resulting in unmounting the entire Home component and so it unmounts also the subroutes.

You have to move the subroutes one level up, for example in your Routes.js next to where you define the home route. Or you can remove `exact` and threat the Home component as component that renders all the common elements (e.g. the header and the footer) but in this case I would not call it Home but maybe `Main` or so.

Comment: If i move subroutes to the upper level, how can i use Home Page's Template in forgot-password route? Forgot-password route only has form, that's all. Template is in HomePage. Can't i just use different Layouts and Nested routes belongs to these Layouts? :/

Comment: You can reuse the boilerplate by removing the `exact` from the Home. That results in all the routes under `/` to share the same 'parent' route. With all the consequences. So maybe what you want is a common parent component under `/` (without `exact`) that has the boilerplate (that is why I would call it Main) . On it you have multiple routes (home, forgotpass, etc) which are `exact`. In that way you share the common elements between components

Answer (score 0):

Problem was "order" i put HomePage route after Dashboard, it is working now.